# Interpretation of Weibull Survival Time Prediction from a Survreg Object

Tags: r, survival, interpretation, weibull-distribution

Code is somewhat like this:

```r
    model=survreg(Surv(Years, Event) ~ asset_age + install_date + 
              no_of_failure, data=weibull_data_train, dist="weibull")

    prediction=predict(model, weibull_data_test)
```

The prediction gives a numeric output in years. My question is, does that output value represent the time from the install_date, or from the time the data was collected onwards?

Answer (score 1):

Only you can answer this question correctly. A predicted survival time will be time from whatever you used as the reference `time = 0` for your `Years` value in your model.

If you used a reference `time = 0` for each item at its `install_date`, then yes: the prediction will be time elapsed from the install date. If you used some other reference for `time = 0`, then it will be time elapsed from that reference time.

Comment: One can predict from a survival model?

Comment: @Ben yes, but what's predicted is a _distribution_ of survival times, given covariate values. See [these pages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bsurvival%5d%20predict*&searchOn=3) on this site. You can get things like median time to event (or other quantiles), probabilities of survival to a specifed time (with confidence intervals), etc.